# frontend maven plugin Failed to execute goal once i add bootstrap to project

Tags: reactjs, spring, jenkins

In our project we use frontend maven plugin this is my pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src</workingDirectory>
                    <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and yarn</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install --frozen-lockfile</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>webpack build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

However once i import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"; My jenkins job fail to compile with the error : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:yarn (webpack build) on project mini-front-products-front: Failed to run task: 'yarn run build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: have you tried running `yarn run build` manually?

Comment: Yes , i had this error yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts build
/bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: I have to run the command "yarn" before to make it work , but the problem is that the command "yarn" create the node_modules directory and I don't want to push it in github

Answer (score 0):

I just upgrade the bootstrap version npm install bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1 and it works for me